# Improve webpack image/css build time?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I have recently taken over a frontend project, and noticed that the initial start time for the `dev` script (with hot module reloading etc) takes extremely long, ~2 minutes.

After setting `verbose` to `true`, I realised almost all of this time is spent recompiling CSS and images which haven't even changed.

The output of the webpack build is a long list that looks like this:

```
---------
Webpack stdout for /Users/myuser/Documents/repos/myApp-frontend/client/modules/App/background.jpg
---------
Hash: 0f500227a855ef9eb67c
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.8
Time: 68ms
                              Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
.webpack.res.1504199219496_875923.js  132 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 1 hidden modules

---------
Webpack stdout for /Users/myuser/Documents/repos/myApp-frontend/client/modules/App/AppAuthorized.css
---------
Hash: 83f1c479b77c7539baeb
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.8
Time: 549ms
                              Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
.webpack.res.1504199221679_732531.js  23.2 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 5 hidden modules
```

The images seem to process quickly, but each of these 2kb css files is taking half a second to compile, and there are dozens of them.

**Here's what my webpack config looks like:**

```
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');
var postcssFocus = require('postcss-focus');
var postcssReporter = require('postcss-reporter');
var precss = require('precss');
var syntax = require('postcss-scss');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [
      'client',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'cache-loader!style-loader!css-loader?localIdentName=[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]&modules&importLoaders=1&sourceMap!postcss-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'cache-loader!url-loader?limit=9999999999999',
      },
      {
        test: /\.ico$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
      },
    ],
  },
  postcss: () => ({
    plugins: [
      precss(),
      postcssFocus(),
      cssnext({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'IE > 10'],
      }),
      postcssReporter({
        clearMessages: true,
      }),
    ],
    syntax: syntax,
  }),
};
```

Any advice to speed the CSS compilation up, or cache assets somehow?

Comment: Not a feasible solution, but just curious - does your computer run off a hard drive, or SSD?

Comment: @JonUleis It has an SSD, why?

Comment: Upgrading to an SSD drastically improved my compilation times - since you're already on one, this does sound like a genuinely slow build process.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the performance of Webpack build / hot-reloading, I usually check the following list and make sure I am doing the right thing:

1. For dev mode env, set the correct 'source-map'. Normally, I go with 'eval' which seems to be the fastest. You can find the benchmark here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/?_sm_au_=iHV0NZ57NZfZ44WQ
2. For dev mode env, remove all the optimisation plugins as they take extra time and only use them in production.
3. For dev mode env, check the version of loaders in package.json, especially for css-loader, style-loader and sass-loader because some latest version may slow down the build. Check https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/124 for more details.
4. Upgrading to Babel 6 may give 10%-20% performance boost.
5. Use webpack-dev-server for dev mode env.
6. Always run 'npm outdated' to check any modules are too old.
7. Make sure the computer is not running too slow. Try to restart.